# Neo4J (Cypher) Group the multiple relationships by node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a small recommendation system to recommend players for the next game. The recommendation consists of first the followed players and then the players who the player has played before ordered by the number of games.

The result would be `Player, is_followed (true|false), GameIds`

I have `Player` and `Game` nodes where are related as `Game -[:HAS_PLAYER]-> Player`
and

the `Player` nodes are directly related as `Player -[:FOLLOWS]-> Player`.

My test DB:

```
CREATE (superman:Player {playerID: 'superman', name:'Superman', sanitizedName: 'superman'})
CREATE (batman:Player {playerID: 'batman', name:'Batman', sanitizedName: 'batman'})
CREATE (catwoman:Player {playerID: 'catwoman', name:'Catwoman', sanitizedName: 'catwoman'})
CREATE (lois:Player {playerID: 'lois', name:'Lois Lane', sanitizedName: 'lois lane'})
CREATE (wonderwoman:Player {playerID: 'wonderwoman', name:'Wonder Woman', sanitizedName: 'wonder woman'})
CREATE (aquaman:Player {playerID: 'aquaman', name:'Aquaman', sanitizedName: 'aquaman'})
CREATE (flash:Player {playerID: 'flash', name:'Flash', sanitizedName: 'flash'})
CREATE (cyborg:Player {playerID: 'cyborg', name:'Cyborg', sanitizedName: 'cyborg'})
CREATE (joker:Player {playerID: 'joker', name:'Joker', sanitizedName: 'joker'})
CREATE (lex:Player {playerID: 'lex', name:'Lex Luthor', sanitizedName: 'lex luthor'})
CREATE (green:Player {playerID: 'green', name:'Green Lantern', sanitizedName: 'green lantern'})

CREATE (g1:Game {gameId:"game-1"})
CREATE (g1)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(superman)
CREATE (g1)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(aquaman)
CREATE (g1)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(batman)
CREATE (g1)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(flash)

CREATE (g2:Game {gameId:"game-2"})
CREATE (g2)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(superman)
CREATE (g2)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(batman)
CREATE (g2)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(joker)
CREATE (g2)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(lex)

CREATE (g3:Game {gameId:"game-3"})
CREATE (g3)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(flash)
CREATE (g3)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(lois)
CREATE (g3)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(wonderwoman)
CREATE (g3)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(aquaman)

CREATE (g4:Game {gameId:"game-4"})
CREATE (g4)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(joker)
CREATE (g4)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(cyborg)
CREATE (g4)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(wonderwoman)
CREATE (g4)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(green)

CREATE (g5:Game {gameId:"game-5"})
CREATE (g5)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"0"}]->(catwoman)
CREATE (g5)-[:HAS_PLAYERS {teamId:"1"}]->(green)

CREATE (batman)-[:FOLLOWS]->(superman)
CREATE (batman)-[:FOLLOWS]->(catwoman)

CREATE (lex)-[:FOLLOWS]->(joker)
CREATE (joker)-[:FOLLOWS]->(lex)
;
```

[image: Batman result]

With this data, I want to recommend to Batman a player for his next game and the result has to be:

```
superman true  [game-1, game-2]
catwoman true  []
aquaman  false [game-1]
flash    false [game-1]
joker    false [game-2]
lex      false [game-2]
```

UPDATE:
I have the next query but the followed players are missing:

```
MATCH (u:Player{playerID:"batman"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)<-[:HAS_PLAYERS]-(g:Game)-[:HAS_PLAYERS]->(p:Player) 
RETURN p, EXISTS((u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p)) AS is_followed, COUNT(g) AS num_games, collect(g) AS games
ORDER BY num_games DESC
```

Thank you!

UPDATE 2

This approach could be more 'readable' but the performance is much worse than the accepted answer.

```
MATCH (u:Player{playerID:"batman"})
CALL {
    WITH u
    MATCH (u)<-[:HAS_PLAYERS]-(g:Game)-[:HAS_PLAYERS]->(p:Player) 
    RETURN p

    UNION

    WITH u
    MATCH (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p:Player)
    RETURN p
}
WITH p,
    EXISTS((u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p)) AS is_followed,
    [(u)<-[:HAS_PLAYERS]-(g:Game)-[:HAS_PLAYERS]->(p) | g.gameId] AS games
RETURN p.name, is_followed, size(games) AS num_games, games
ORDER BY num_games DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not get catwoman because you only match :Player related to batman through a :Game node, you need to also match (u:Player {playerID:"batman"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(p:Player)

```
MATCH (u:Player{playerID:"batman"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)<-[:HAS_PLAYERS]-(g:Game)-[:HAS_PLAYERS]->(p:Player) 
RETURN p.playerID, EXISTS((u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p)) AS is_followed, COUNT(g) AS num_games, collect(g.gameId) AS games
ORDER BY num_games DESC
union
match (u:Player{playerID:"batman"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(p:Player)
where not exists( (u)<-[:HAS_PLAYERS]-(:Game)-[:HAS_PLAYERS]->(p:Player) )
RETURN p.playerID, true AS is_followed, 0 AS num_games, [] AS games
```

[image]

(could not think of a way to do it wouthout union, but it might be possible)

Comment: Thank you very much. I continued to work on it and my approach has a UNION as well but yours has a better performance.